# Are students being adversely affected by cranks or trolls in online math forums?

Tags: secondary-education

Does anyone know of any cases of students being adversely affected by cranks or trolls in online math forums (e.g. sci.math)? Are they even a minor problem?

Dan

Comment: I don't know of any particular examples, but I also don't see how this is a problem that is particular to mathematics.  There are Cantor cranks, and flat Earthers, and young Earthers, and racists, and all manner of other cranks and trolls on the interwebs.  It seems to me that one of the jobs of the secondary instructor is to help students spot those kind of cranks, and work out the flaws in their arguments. ;)

Comment: Do you have relevant examples that motivated this question?

Comment: Honestly, I think the perpetuation of things like "infinity is just a concept" is a bigger issue. Unless you count that as cranky too.

Comment: Do you mean things like $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}j=\frac{-1}{12}$?

Comment: What kind of answers are you looking for and why?

Comment: @NateBade If the answer isn't obvious to the teachers here, I guess internet math cranks and trolls are simply not a big problem in schools. Good to know.

Comment: I don't think it is a huge, self evident issue.  Some of the common problems and benefits of crowd source opinion exist.  But not a huge massive danger.  I actually think problems are more on the margin.  Over-reliance on site Q&A and not even doing own Google search. Or sometimes responders have their own blind spots and don't think about question (person asks for help on math for physics and is told to go to Rudin analysis).  At least so far, benefits are way above detriments and SE has not been degraded the way Amazon reviews have turned from thoughtful long pieces to gamed short responses.

Comment: P.s.  Not even trolling...but at first I thought this "question" was directed against me!  ;-)

Comment: Yeah, honestly the closest I've seen (besides the comment below) is youtubers and other "science" celebrities trying to make math "cool" or "mind blowing" and so deriving unintuitive results poorly and claiming them as math. I've talked to a couple of students who think that Banch-Tarksi is amazing, but also think that the pieces of measurable. @fmline's example is the other one: after numberphile put up their video on this series last year I had a handful of students who wanted to talk about their misleading or misunderstood proof. Ah well, teaching moments as below.

Comment: Much more common from what I've seen is really shockingly incorrect beliefs from people in industry, especially programming. There's a rise  finitism combined with a real lack of understand of mathematical proof.

Comment: @NateBade Is there any indication that these incorrect beliefs are formulated as a result of online misinformation?

Comment: In the second case, yes-ish. Almost every such conversation begins with either a link to an article or youtube video, but often the conversationalist wants to express their own ideas and is only using the web resource to (1) show that mathematics as a discipline is bunk/biased/clinging to false dogma and so use the invalidity of the field as a jumping off point or (2) use the resource as a base of legitimacy from which to spin out their own theory. It's not clear to me that in either case the incorrect beliefs are caused but the resource instead of enabled or reinforced.

Comment: @NateBade I'm guessing they don't get to actually apply their unconventional ideas in their work. Without the constraints of either the real world or rigorous proof, just about anything would go.

Comment: @NateBade Example: I know of this IT guy (supposedly) who came up with his own definition of a derivative of a function, but it blows up for linear functions and at points of inflections. Rather than rework his definition, he declares derivatives in these cases to be "undefined!" Clearly, he won't be able to apply it in the real world.

Answer (score 6):

I had a couple but one in particular sticks out: years ago I was teaching a summer program for middle school students, one of the other instructors suggested I show my students the youtube video "Imagining the 10th Dimension." So I watched the first 5 minutes and it looked like a nice flatland-like explanation of higher dimensional space, so I let my TA show it while I was out of town. It turns out after about 6 minutes of flatland it runs off into a really misguided attempt justify the conformal anomaly (sometimes understood as 10 spacial dimensions) in string theory in terms of "all the possible version of actions in the universe."

It's a great example of bad mathematics/physics (although the author doesn't really understand the difference). It slips from well established mathematics to incorrect and incoherent speculation without batting an eye, and the narrator has an easy authority that says "just trust me." My poor TA luckily figured out something was seriously wrong and told the students that they shouldn't take it seriously. We took it as a teaching opportunity and had an hour long lesson about evaluating claims, thinking for yourself, and the difference between speculation and proof.

I had a conversation about it with the person who suggested me the video, but he didn't really seem to understand the problem...

Comment: This is an eye-opening example, and I'm glad you shared it. However, I think it doesn't really answer the original question (Are students adversely affected?), and it's worth emphasizing what you said towards the end: you turned this situation into an occasion for a class discussion about precisely this kind of phenomenon. So, I think an answer to the original question is, "Yeah, probably". And as far as what we can do about it... we cab simply let students know this is possible in reality and to talk about it with them.

Comment: I think I would go farther and say that while they clearly could be, they sort of don't seem to be. As Dan pointed out in the comments under his question the lack of response here probably indicates that it's not that big of a problem. But it could also be that the students who would be effected arn't talking to their instructors.